# JayData not populating objects from OData

Tags: javascript, odata, jaydata

I have a working OData endpoint where I can look at individual datapoints. (For example, localhost/myData/person(10) has the data of the 10th person.)

However my objects' values in my JayData javascript are not being populated.
When I print:

> console.log(person[10]);

Every object parameter in initData is undefined.
[image]

My full script is:

```
var ctx = new WebApplication.resource_dbEntities({ name: 'oData', oDataServiceHost: 'http://localhost:8080/Resource/example.svc' });

    ctx.onReady(function() {
            ctx.person.toArray().then(function(person){
            console.log("Person[10] is:");
            console.log(person[10]);
              person.forEach(function(p) {
                   //Always prints "undefined" :(
                   console.log(p.person_lastname);
               });
          })

          .fail(function(r){
            console.log(r);
          });
        });
```

**UPDATE:**
The server is most definitely sending data - see a clip from the network pannel on the webpage.
[image]

*Note: I have posted additional details on the [JayData forum](http://jaydata.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=240&sid=7e05a434f4b4b5dc3242ef54f9c59725).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Eclipse auto-generates entities from mySQL and link that to persistence.xml. The variables (even though they were private?!) in person.java did not match the initData variables.

Once I opened person.java and changed

> ```
> @Column(name="project_id")
> private int projectId;
> ```

```
@Column(name="project_budget")
private int projectBudget;

@Column(name="project_client")
private String projectClient;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="project_enddate")
private Date projectEnddate;

@Column(name="project_ffm")
private int projectFfm;

@Column(name="project_manager")
private int projectManager;

@Column(name="project_name")
private String projectName;

@Column(name="project_number")
private String projectNumber;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="project_startdate")
private Date projectStartdate;

@Column(name="project_status")
private int projectStatus;
```

To this:

```
@Id
@Column(name="project_id")
private int project_id;

@Column(name="project_budget")
private int project_budget;

@Column(name="project_client")
private String project_client;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="project_enddate")
private Date project_enddate;

@Column(name="project_ffm")
private int project_ffm;

@Column(name="project_manager")
private int project_manager;

@Column(name="project_name")
private String project_name;

@Column(name="project_number")
private String project_number;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="project_startdate")
private Date project_startdate;

@Column(name="project_status")
private int project_status;
```

Everything worked. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need initData. First see the network panel of your browser and see if your server sends any data.

Comment: Thank you for your response - I have updated the question to reflect your suggestion.